# child_process module has not been loaded yet

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

I'm looking into NodeJS for running a PowerShell script from my JavaScript script. This is the code I found online:

```
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn,child;

child = spawn("powershell.exe",["c:\\test\\mypstest.ps1 -arg1 1"]);

child.stdout.on("data",function(data){
    console.log("Powershell Data: " + data);
});

child.stderr.on("data",function(data){
    console.log("Powershell Errors: " + data);
});

child.on("exit",function(){
   console.log("Powershell Script finished");
});

child.stdin.end(); //end input
```

When I run a live server on the html, I get the following console error:

```
Uncaught Error: Module name "child_process" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
```

When I change

```
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn,child;
```

to

```
var spawn = require(["child_process"]).spawn,child;
```

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: spawn is not a function               index.js
Uncaught Error: Script error for "child_process"          require.js
```

I was under the impression that `child_process.js` was included in the Node.js installation. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why that module hasn't been loaded yet, but you're using the `require` function incorrectly.

See the [docs](https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded).

When you supply an array to `require`, it is going to use the async version of `require`, and you need to supply a callback that will receive the loaded module.

Try something like this:

```
require(["child_process"], function (cp) {
    var spawn = cp.spawn;
    // ... use spawn()
});
```

Comment: After I 'npm init' the folder in which I build my tool, do I need to add NodeJS to my html file somewhere? I feel like my script doesn't load child_process since it doesn't know what it is. So for example <script src="js/node.js></script> in the header of my html. I have installed NodeJS on my computer but I don't see how my script knows that.

Comment: @MartFijten No you don't need to do that. `npm init` creates a node app with a package.json file. When you run your app via `npm start` or whatever you're doing, it knows that you're running a node application and will look for your various dependencies in `node_modules` folder either locally or globally. For modules like `child_process`, those are already bundled with node, so you shouldn't need to do anything extra to require them

Comment: I don't see the module `child_process` in my `node_modules` folder anywhere. Could that be the problem?

Comment: @MartFijten No, I think it should be bundled with Node. I don't see a separate `child_process` folder in my project either - I think it should just work. When you try the async version of `require`, do you see `cp` set to the child process module?